# Hibernate: Duplicated items with OnetoOne relation persisting a List

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

```
@Entity
public class TestPair implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JsonProperty("target_Test")
    private Test targetTest;
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JsonProperty("source_Test")
        private Test sourceTest;
...}

@Entity
public class Test {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String shortname;
...}
```

I have a `List<TestPair>` that i want to persist using spring boot CrudRepository.

TestPair's contain Test's and these Test's are the same along some of the TestPair's.

When i use the saveAll method, it persists the objects but the Test's that are equal it inserts new one's, creating lots of repeating elements in the db.

I've create the equals and hashcode for this classes.

Comment: So far I understand you mean on queries created, right?

Comment: @JonathanJohx it has multiple entries on the Test sql table. 
For example i have `List<TestPair>` with:

`[ {TestPair:  {sourceTest:{name: test1, shortname t1} {targetTest:{name: test2, shortname t2}}} ,  {TestPair:  {sourceTest:{name: test1, shortname t1} {targetTest:{name: test3, shortname t3}}} ]`.  It will duplicate the entry for `{name: test1, shortname t1}` on the database and on queries, instead of only creating one entry for that object. If i try to use the shortname as @Id it throws sql duplicate entry errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

Instead of using the crud saveAll for the Hashset, i'm saving one by one.

```
for(TestPair tPair : TPairs){
    testRepository.save(tPair.getSourceTest());
    testRepository.save(tPair.getTargetTest());
    testPairRepository.save(tPair);
}
```

And changed the classes to:

```
@Entity
public class TestPair implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JsonProperty("target_Test")
    private Test targetTest;
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JsonProperty("source_Test")
    private Test sourceTest;
}

@Entity
public class Test {
    private String name;
    @Id
    private String shortname;
}
```

This way hibernate merges the objects, not creating new one's. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Check the auto generation logic for both the ids. If it is auto incremental then all the created entity will be different hence new entry is getting created every time.